# GreenFunction for Helmholtz equation in circular region

Tags: equation-solving

Dirichlet problem for the Helmholtz operator in a rectangle can be resolved according to the Reference as `GreenFunction[{-(Laplacian[u[x, y],{x, y}] + 400 u[x, y]),  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},  u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], {m, n}]`, which returns $$4 \underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\underset{K[2]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{\sin (m \pi  K[1]) \sin (\pi  x K[1]) \sin (n \pi  K[2]) \sin (\pi  y K[2])}{\pi ^2 K[1]^2+\pi ^2 K[2]^2-400}.$$
However, by simply replacing the region `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]` by `Circle[{0, 0}, 1]`, no solution is returned. Could someone give a hint please?

Comment: Did you consider change of coordinates to "Polar" too?